# convert dictionary with lists to csv file where the columns are the keys and the values are in the rows

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

Hi i have a dictionary which contains indicator of comprise it looks like that:

```
{'url' : [ 'malware.com ', 'hack.net ', 'paypalz.org' ] 'IP' ['104.223.89.166' , 104.223.89.136] 'emailIdentifier' : ['liler@bikurcholim.net']}
```

i need to convert it to csv where the keys are the columns and the values are in rows. i tried to find solutions in stackoverflow flow to this case but i didn't find one. any syggestions how to do it ?

thank you

```
with open('\\cybernet\\cyber_indicators.csv', 'w') as csv_file:

    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, keys)

    for key, value in dictionary.items():

        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: looks nice but where is the method to export it to csv ?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html converts dict to dataframe and you can convert the dataframe to csv using https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html


I hope I'm getting this right :P

Comment: If your keys are the columns and the values the according values for the rows, how come they differ in number? What output do you expect?

Comment: the output shout be like

Comment: usuing https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html is a problem becuae the arrys are not in the same length

Comment: the output shout be like   url IP emailIdentifier
malware.com 104.223.89.166 liler@bikurcholim.net
hack.net 104.223.89.136] 
paypalz.org

Comment: any idea ? thank you

Comment: Pls edit your question. Don't leave valuable info in the comments.

Comment: You need [pandas.DataFrame.transpose](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html?highlight=transpose#pandas.DataFrame.transpose)

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
dictionary={'url' : [ 'malware.com ', 'hack.net ', 'paypalz.org' ] ,'IP' : ['104.223.89.166' , '104.223.89.136'] ,'emailIdentifier' : ['liler@bikurcholim.net']}
list_temp=[]
with open('data.csv','w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(dictionary.keys())
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        list_temp.append(value)
    list_last=[x for x in dictionary.values()]
    max_length=0
    for item in list_last:
        if(len(item)>max_length):
            max_length=len(item)
    for item in list_last:
        append_count=max_length-len(item)
        for i in range(append_count):
            item.append('')
    zipped_list=list_last=set(zip(*list_temp))
    for item in zipped_list:
        writer.writerow(item)
```

data.csv

```
url,IP,emailIdentifier
malware.com ,104.223.89.166,liler@bikurcholim.net
paypalz.org,,
hack.net ,104.223.89.136,
```

Comment: writer.writerow(item)

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: @PenTestPenTest  Everything is inside the with open('data.csv','w') as csv_file:

Comment: @PenTestPenTest You are getting that error b'coz your writer.writerow(item) is not inside the with open statement. Just copy the code as is and try.

Comment: thank you it is almost perfect however , is there any way to delete empty cells ?

Comment: @PenTestPenTest Not that i know of. It is the csv format.